# Wordpress URL Parameters on GoDaddy

Tags: php, wordpress, mod-rewrite

I am currently making a website (http://tannernelson.me/ehs)

It's hosted on Godaddy, and I'm using wordpress as a CMS.

I want to be able to make:

```
http://tannernelson.me/ehs/school/academics/teachers/jsmith
```

turn into

```
http://tannernelson.me/ehs/index.php?pagename=teachers&detail=jsmith
```

So, basically, if there are 4 segments to the url (school/academics/teachers/jsmith) I want the last one to be a variable. So the fourth segment of any url will be the variable "detail"

My current URL rewrite is currently

```
# Mod Rewrite
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /ehs/index.php [L]
Options -Multiviews
```

It won't work any other way, even with the default WordPress .htaccess file. And I have no idea what that means, or what kind of request URI is made out of it. It's really confusing.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you have right now means:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

If the requested filename **is not** (`!`) a regular file `-f` and if the requested filename **is not** (`!`) a directory `-d` then:

```
RewriteRule . /ehs/index.php [L]
```

Match any single character (`.`) and if a match is found rewrite the URL to `/ehs/index.php` and then make this the last rule (`[L]`) so don't process any further rules.

This doesn't look like what you want, but seems to be working. `http://tannernelson.me/ehs/school/academics/teachers/jsmith` serves up (I think) `http://tannernelson.me/ehs/index.php` because I get a custom 404 not found page.

Try the following `.htaccess` code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Redirect the ehs/school/academics/$1/$2 URIs to /ehs/index.php?pagename=$1&detail=$2
RewriteRule ^ehs/school/academics/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /ehs/index.php?pagename=$1&detail=$2 [L]

# Otherwise if the requested URI is not found (not a file nor a directory)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

#Redirect everything else to index.php
RewriteRule .* /ehs/index.php [L]

Options -Multiviews
```

I just tested this on my Apache server and it works.